# Check, if results are continuous

Tags: php, mysql

I got a little thing to solve with MySQL and PHP.

Let's assume I got a table with this rows:

- id (`int`)
- value (`boolean`)
- date (`datetime`)

Now I would like to check, if there are 5 or more entries that have continuously the value `false`.

Example:

```
id | value | date
1 - true - 01.01.1970
2 - false - 02.01.1970
3 - false - 03.01.1970
4 - false - 04.01.1970
5 - false - 05.01.1970
6 - false - 06.01.1970
```

Here we have 5 entries that are continuously `false`. So my script should return `true` (yes, there are 5 or more entries, that are continuously `false`).

This example should return `false`:

```
id | value | date
1 - false - 01.01.1970
2 - false - 02.01.1970
3 - true - 03.01.1970
4 - false - 04.01.1970
5 - true - 05.01.1970
6 - false - 06.01.1970
```

This should return `false` (no, there are not 5 or more entries continuously `false`).

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: how about `select count(id) where value = 'false'` ? then use if statement to handle conditions?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile it should be  continuously the value false. so with your suggestion it might not be achieved.

Comment: Question title is misleading. Could you update it to be related to question? And you don't need to specify technologies in title, you have tags for that.

Comment: The problem is, that I want to determine, if there is a continuity of `false` results or if it's interrupted. So I can not use `where value = 'false'`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the title. I did that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible using loop eg:

```
$array = [[1, true], [1, false], [1, false],[1, false],[1, false],[1, false]]; // Your array

$counter = 0;
$hasFoundFiveContinuesFalse = false;
foreach($array as $item) {
    if($item[1] == false) {
        $counter++;
    } else {
        $counter = 0;
    }

    if($counter >= 5 ) {
        $hasFoundFiveContinuesFalse = true; // if we have found 5 times false then break the loop and set hasFoundFiveContinuesFalse to true 
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($hasFoundFiveContinuesFalse);
```

This might not be a perfect way but it should work.

Comment: And the date column. the date column Is important voor the check

Comment: so do you want to check for a specific date with continues false ?

Comment: I can just order by date in the sql query so there are always the latest X entries, which are processed by this.

Comment: @SPQRInc ORDER BY date doenst confirm continuation and ORDER BY date isn't smart because date is a string format.